# Flutter Listview Builder SwitchListTile flags - Allow One Switch flag at a time to be set to true

Tags: flutter, dart

Using Flutter, I created an input box with Add and Remove buttons. Using a ListView Builder, clicking Add button adds a new row with a SwitchListTile. I can add multiple rows. Right now, I can set the switch flag to true in each row. I want to add a limitation that only one row at a time can have the switch flag set to true. Could you please advice how to do this properly. I have the following code below. Thank You

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final List<String> names = <String>[];
  final List<bool> flags = <bool>[];
  TextEditingController mc = TextEditingController();

  addItemToList() {
    setState(() {
      if (mc.text.isNotEmpty) {
        names.add(mc.text);
        flags.add(false);
      }
    });
  }

  deleteItemFromList() {
    setState(() {
      names.removeLast();
    });
  }

  int index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget space = SizedBox(width: 100, height: 5, child: Text(""));
    Widget myinput = TextField(
        controller: mc,
        decoration:
            InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Name'));
    Widget btnAdd =
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: addItemToList, child: Text('Add'));
    Widget btnRemove =
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: deleteItemFromList, child: Text('Remove'));
    Widget mylist = SizedBox(
      width: 800,
      height: 500,
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: names.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                SwitchListTile(
                    title: Text(names[index], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
                    value: flags[index],
                    onChanged: (bool value) {
                      {
                        setState(() {
                          flags[index] = value;
                        });
                      }
                      ;
                    })
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      space,
                      myinput,
                      space,
                      btnAdd,
                      space,
                      btnRemove,
                      space,
                      mylist,
                      space
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it is working i believe, you can also use model class for each item

Comment: Yeasin! The restrict code to allow only one switch flag set to true was not added.

Comment: Ok I get it now, you like to have it like radio button

Answer (score 0):

Instead of names and flags list, make one Data class. Then make list of that class.

**Data Class:**

```
class DataModel{
  int id;
  String name;
  bool isSelected;
  DataModel({required this.id, required this.name, this.isSelected = false});
}
```

**For code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}


//Data Class
class DataModel{
  int id;
  String name;
  bool isSelected;
  DataModel({required this.id, required this.name, this.isSelected = false});
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
//Data Class List
  final List<DataModel> names = <DataModel>[];
 
  TextEditingController mc = TextEditingController();

  addItemToList() {
    setState(() {
      if (mc.text.isNotEmpty) {
        names.add(DataModel(id:names.length+1, name:mc.text,));
       
      }
    });
  }

  deleteItemFromList() {
    setState(() {
      names.removeLast();
    });
  }

  int index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget space = SizedBox(width: 100, height: 5, child: Text(""));
    Widget myinput = TextField(
        controller: mc,
        decoration:
            InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Name'));
    Widget btnAdd =
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: addItemToList, child: Text('Add'));
    Widget btnRemove =
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: deleteItemFromList, child: Text('Remove'));
    Widget mylist = SizedBox(
      width: 800,
      height: 500,
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: names.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                SwitchListTile(
                    title: Text(names[index].name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
                    value: names[index].isSelected,
                    onChanged: (bool value) {
                      {
                      //set all values to false first
                        names.forEach((fl)=>fl.isSelected=false);
                        setState(() {
                          names[index].isSelected = value;
                        });
                      }
                      ;
                    })
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      space,
                      myinput,
                      space,
                      btnAdd,
                      space,
                      btnRemove,
                      space,
                      mylist,
                      space
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```